Unable to Submit Partical View form to Controller
I am trying to submit a form to my MVC controller. The form is in a partial view and when I hit submit it returns with a 500 error at the path for the action and controller: "https://localhost:44383/WIZ/Form/CreateTicketForm". I am just submitting the form and view model to the controller. I am not using ajax or any other JavaScript. When I gill out the form all of the required fields are completed. Below is the code for my form:
@model TicketWizard.ViewModels.FormViewModel
@addTagHelper*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create New Ticket";
}

<form method="post" id="formBody" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="CreateTicketForm" asp-controller="Form">
    <input asp-for="User.CAC_EDIPI" id="userEDIPI" hidden /> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group bg-light row pb-3">

                    <div class="col-3">
                        <label class="fw-bold" asp-for="Ticket.Priority" tabindex="-1"></label><b style="color:red;"> *</b>
                        <select asp-for="Ticket.Priority" asp-items="@ViewBag.PriorityDropDown" class="form-select" id="priorityId" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Select the impact best fitting the scope of the opportunity">
                            <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Ticket.Priority" class="text-danger" id="priorityValid"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-3">
                        <label class="fw-bold" asp-for="Ticket.NumUsers" tabindex="-1"></label><b style="color:red;"> *</b>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="numUsers" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Ticket.NumUsers" class="text-danger" id="numUsersValid"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-3">
                        <label asp-for="Ticket.RoomNumber" class="fw-bold" tabindex="-1">
                    </label><b style="color:red;"> *</b>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" asp-for="Ticket.RoomNumber" id="roomNumber" data-toggle="tooltip" title="A room number is required if you work in the GCC." />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Ticket.RoomNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <label asp-for="Ticket.CubeNumber" class="fw-bold" tabindex="-1">
                    </label><b style="color:red;"> *</b>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" asp-for="Ticket.CubeNumber" id="cubeNumber" data-toggle="tooltip" title="A cube number is required if you work in the GCC." />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Ticket.CubeNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row pb-3">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <p class="col-6 fw-bold" tabindex="-1">Is this issue causing a workstoppage?<b style="color:red;"> *</b></p>
                        <div class="col-6 btn-group" role="group">
                            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Ticket.WorkStoppageYes" class="btn-check" id="yesCheck" onclick="workStoppageRequired()" autocomplete="off">
                            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="yesCheck">Yes</label>

                            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Ticket.WorkStoppageYes" class="btn-check" id="noCheck" onclick="workStoppageNotRequired()" autocomplete="off">
                            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="noCheck">No</label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <span class="text-danger" id="workStoppageWarning" style="display: none;">Please select an option.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group row bg-light pb-3">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label class="fw-bold" asp-for="Ticket.SubmitterEDIPI" tabindex="-1"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Ticket.SubmitterName" id="submitterName" class="form-control unaccessible" type="text" readonly>
                        <input asp-for="Ticket.SubmitterEDIPI" id="submitterEDIPI" hidden>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label class="fw-bold" asp-for="Ticket.AlternateEDIPI" tabindex="-1"></label>
                        <div class="autocomplete" data-toggle="tooltip"
                             title="Only add name if the Submitter will not be the point of contact.">
                            <input asp-for="Ticket.AltPocName" id="altPOCInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name..." type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Find RCC-C users by last name">
                            <input asp-for="Ticket.AlternateEDIPI" id="altPocEDIPI" hidden>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row pb-3">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label asp-for="Ticket.ServiceId" class="fw-bold" tabindex="-1">Services</label>
                        <select asp-for="Ticket.ServiceId" class="form-select" asp-items="@ViewBag.ServiceAreasDown" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                title="Select the service that can assist with this issue" id="ticketService">
                            <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label asp-for="Ticket.TeamId" class="fw-bold" tabindex="-1">Teams</label>
                        <select asp-for="Ticket.TeamId" class="form-select" asp-items="@ViewBag.TeamDropDown" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                title="Select the team that can assist with this issue" id="ticketTeam">
                            <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <span class="text-danger" id="teamServicesWarning" style="display: none;">Please select either a service or a team.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row bg-light pb-3">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label asp-for="Ticket.Details" class="fw-bold" tabindex="-1">Details<b style="color:red;"> *</b></label>
                        <textarea asp-for="Ticket.Details" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Provide a detailed description of the issue." id="ticketDetails">
                        </textarea>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Ticket.Details" class="text-danger" id="detailsValid"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="btn-group float-right" role="group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-1" id="submitFormBtn">Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

</form>
@*//Client-side validation*@

@section Scripts {   
  

    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}

Here is the code for the controller:
 //POST-Submit Form
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public IActionResult CreateTicketForm(FormViewModel formViewModel)
 {
     UserVO userVO = this.cookieAuthenticationService.GetUser(HttpContext, out bool edipiFound, true);
     string fullName = HomeController.CapitalizeFirstLetter(userVO.lastName) + ", " + HomeController.CapitalizeFirstLetter(userVO.firstName) + " " + HomeController.CapitalizeFirstLetter(userVO.mi) + " " + HomeController.FindAcronym(userVO.rank.rank);
     string WorkStoppage = "No";
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         return View();

     }

     try
     {

         using (SqlConnection con = HomeController.OpenConnection(WizConnString))
         {
             SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("usp_CreateTicket", con);
             sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

             sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SubmitterEDIPI", (int)userVO.edipi);
             sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SubmitterName", fullName);
             sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Details", formViewModel.Ticket.Details);
             sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Priority", formViewModel.Ticket.Priority);
             sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("NumUsers", formViewModel.Ticket.NumUsers);
             if (formViewModel.Ticket.WorkStoppageYes == "true")
             {
                 WorkStoppage = "Yes";
             } else if(formViewModel.Ticket.WorkStoppageNo == "true")
             {
                 WorkStoppage = "No";
             }
             sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("WorkStoppage", WorkStoppage);                   
             sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RoomNumber", formViewModel.Ticket.RoomNumber);
             sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CubeNumber", formViewModel.Ticket.CubeNumber);
             sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ServiceId", formViewModel.Ticket.ServiceId);
             sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TeamId", formViewModel.Ticket.TeamId);

             if (formViewModel.Ticket.AlternateEDIPI != null)
             {
                 sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AltEDIPI", formViewModel.Ticket.AlternateEDIPI);
                 sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AltPocName", formViewModel.Ticket.AltPocName);
             }          

             sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }

         return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         PortalLogger.WriteLog("Error. Unable to create ticket for  " + (int)userVO.edipi + ". " + ex.ToString());
         throw new Exception("Error. Unable to create ticket for " + (int)userVO.edipi + ". " + ex.ToString());
     }
 }

Here is the code for the Ticket model:
    public class Ticket
    {
        //Required
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("POC/Submitter")]      
        public long SubmitterEDIPI { get; set; }
        public string SubmitterName { get; set; }
        public string SubmitterPhone { get; set; }
        public string SubmitterEmail { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Alternative POC")]
        public string AlternateEDIPI { get; set; }
        public string AltPocName { get; set; }
        public string AltPOCPhone { get; set; }
        public string AltPOCEmail { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }       
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A priority must be provided.")]
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public int NumUsers { get; set; }
        public string WorkStoppageYes { get; set; }
        public string WorkStoppageNo { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Room Number")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A room number must be provided if the user works in the GCC.")]
        public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Cube Number")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A cube number must be provided if the user works in the GCC.")]
        public string CubeNumber { get; set; }
    }
}

I have gone to the even viewer and there are no errors listed. Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated! The error is not detailed in dev tools, it shows the form payload being passed but nothing happens. When I set break-points in the controller action they are never reached.

500 error at the path for the action and controller -> points to existing issue in the server side, but you mentioned that the breakpoint in the controller wasn't triggered. Is there any filters or middleware in your app which stopped the request?

I had a test in my side which creating a partial view to put the form and create a controller which only return View, and they all work well. But I noticed that the url for form submit request is /Form/CreateTicketForm and there's no /WIZ. I'm afraid there's some other codes required for reproducing your issue. Could you pls provide a minimal sample for reproducing your issue?

I'm afraid you are using Area in your project and WIZ is your Area name?
